# Trying to concatenate an AngularJS var with a Laravel Blade var

Tags: angularjs, templates, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm developing a Laravel app. First I was making a form with the FormBuilder so I had this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'delete', 'route' => ['clientes.destroy', $cliente->id]]) !!}
```

When I decided to start using AngularJS I realized that I had to remove the FormBuilder because now I have to print the "cliente id" with Angular (using ng-repeat). So I changed my code to this (If you don't know about Laravel ignore the hidden inputs):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}/@{{ cliente.id }}">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

The problem is that the @{{ cliente.id }} is breaking my app so it doesnt show my clients.

A little more of context: This form is inside a table of Clients and it displays a button to delete the client.

How should I print the variable?

EDIT: If I remove the action attribute from my form, all clients are showed so I'm 100% sure the problem is with this concatenation.

EDIT2: This works

```
<form method="POST" action="@{{ cliente.id }}">
```

And this also works

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}">
```

EDIT3: The whole repeater.

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in buscador.clientes">
    <td>@{{ cliente.tipo.nombre }}</td>
    <td>@{{ cliente.nombre }}</td>
    <td>@{{ cliente.direccion  }}</td>
    <td>@{{ cliente.telefono  }}</td>
    <td>@{{ cliente.email  }}</td>
    <td>@{{ cliente.rubro  }}</td>
    <td>
    <form method="POST" action="@{{ '{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}/' + cliente.id }}">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: it looks like ``{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}`` was not parsed and replaced with string by PHP.

Comment: are you sure you have this form in blade template and not in angular template?

Comment: all this code is inside index.blade.php and as you can see in EDIT2 they both work individually and the problem appears when I try to concatenate them

Comment: so please click Ctrl+U to see source code, there **should** be line with ``<form>`` tag generated by PHP. Paste that line here.

Comment: with your given code it output this:  <form method="POST" action="{{ '{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}/' + cliente.id }}"> (nothing is parsed)

Comment: If I go back to my original code it output this: <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/clientes/%7Bclientes%7D/{{ cliente.id }}"> (at least blade is parsed)

Comment: so we're near the bug :) I'm wondering why PHP didn't parsed this ``{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}``.

Comment: Got it :) Right now I'll amend my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** First of all you need to change AngularJS curly braces not to conflict with Blade template engine:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []) 

  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    // To prevent the conflict of `{{` and `}}` symbols
    // between Blade template engine and AngularJS templating we need
    // to use different symbols for AngularJS.

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%=');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });
```

You're currently using `@{{ }}` and that's the source of conflict, that's why PHP can't parse your code correctly. I suggest to use `<%= %>` because it's the often used construction, you can find it in [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/).

**2.** Then, since Angular 1.2.x, you can [bind only one expression as action](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to).

So, this code should work:

```
<form 
  method="POST" 
  action="<%= '{{ route('clientes.destroy') }}/' + cliente.id %>">
```

Comment: Yes. It is: Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2027-29%20%5B')%5D&p2='%7B%7B%20route('clientes.destroy')
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at hc.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:186:421)
    at hc.readString (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:189:153)
    at hc.lex (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:184:359)
    at ib.parse (https:/...

Comment: can you please view result source code of generated blade template and copy-paste line with form tag here

Comment: Of course, with your given code it output this: <tbody><!-- ngRepeat: cliente in buscador.clientes --></tbody>

Comment: it's not that line, I need line with ``<form>`` tag

Comment: Its not printed. Nothing inside <tr ng-repeat="cliente in buscador.clientes"></tr> is printed. Do you want me to add the full code in the question?

Comment: yes, it will be helpful if you add whole code between ``<tr ng-repeat="…">`` and ``</tr>`` tags

Comment: It did the job! plus I had to add "null" as the second parameter of route() to make work since its waiting the parameter. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution without modifying anything would be:

`action="{{url('urlportal')}}/@{{cliente.id}}"`